# Questions migrated to sites with numbers in their names display bare URL in revision history

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, migration, revisions-list

Question migrated to a site with a number in its name:
[image]

A bare URL is displayed in the image.

Normal migration:

[image]

The destination site is displayed as a link with no bare URL.